# Speeding up tensorflow 2.0 inference?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Am following the excellent post here:

https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/

but am wondering if there are additional routes to speeding up inference for tensorflow 2.0 models.

Am noticing there is quite a bit of over-head on a single call for a simple model. For example, calling a single row prediction might be .5 ms while 2500 row prediction is about 50 ms. So that is only 100x longer with 2500x data.

Is there a nice path to calling these from cython or simply using RT? This is a smallish network and should be fast on CPU.